# Images not showing up in dreamweaver design, but show up in live

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am currently working on a project on web designing using Dreamweaver. So I have set up my site and `home.html`. I've also added the necessary images in an `images` folder in the project root.

Here’s the problem: when I drag the image from my assets panel and put it in design, the image doesn't show up, but I see a grey box and an icon in it. Now when I see the live view, I can see the image.

How can I see the image in design view, so as to adjust its size proportionately?

[image: Working image]

[image: Broken image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>home</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/webDes.jpg" alt="" width="280" height="226" longdesc="images/webDes.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ,I got the problem . the image was made in illustrator, and when I exported it in  .JPEG  format , I chose CMYK. that was the wrong move , I  Later exported again , but chose RGB and it worked  !

Answer (score -1):

Your code has errors in it, possibly attributing to Dreamweaver not showing the images. Your web browser may be ignoring the errors, but dreamweaver isn't. HTML does not require colons, which you have two of. Here is come cleaned-up code.

Cleaned up your code a bit - try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>home</title> 
</head> 
<body> <img src="images/webDes.jpg" alt="" width="280" height="226" longdesc="images/webDes.jpg" /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: i still have the problem

Comment: The code I provided was valid HTML markup, whereas the provided code contained 3 main errors. xmlns attribute was referenced properly, and two random semicolons removed.