# My image doesn't show in DreamWeaver

Tags: html, css, image, dreamweaver, display

I've checked many times that it is the right name and right linking. Another image shows when I put it in there, but when I choose the other image it doesn't work. And I have no idea why.

My html:

```
<nav id="leftnav_1">
<img src="bilder/logo.png" alt="header" title="Longhorn" style=" width:300px;"/>
</nav>
```

And my CSS:

```
#leftnav_1 {
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Try to rename the file and add it to the code. sometimes caching images makes some problems.

Comment: Does the image display when you visit the page on a browser? Is the problem specific to DreamWeaver?

Comment: [Does this post help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769172/images-not-showing-up-in-dreamweaver-design-but-show-up-in-live?rq=1)

Comment: I uploaded it in a browser and it appeard. Although the positions of all the boxes was in different places then in DW. I always use the Live-button when I work in DW. Thank u for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `src="bilder/logo.png"` attribute, the image should be a file called "logo.png" inside a folder called "bilder" that is in the same directory as the HTML file the code is in. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the folder called "bilder" is in the same folder as my HTML file :)